# Connection has been shutdown on phpstorm because of java.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, svn, phpstorm

I get the following error message when trying to commit with subversion on phpstorm 10.0.1 :

> java.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol
>   is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate).

I found people getting the same error message with other environnement. However, I did not find solutions on phpstorm. If some of you encountered the same kind of error, I would be glad to know how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

More a workaround than a real solution, but I solved this issue by selecting 'Use command line client' in PhpStorm's Subversion settings.